# CKEDITOR 5 with Boootstrap 5.3 Dark Theme

Tags: php, html, css, ckeditor, bootstrap-5

I have just found CKEditor and moving away from TinyMCE, but my CKEditor 5 installation on the page is not picking up that the theme on the page is set my Bootstrap

```
<html data-bs-theme="dark" lang="en">
```

How do i get CKE5 to take on the theme?

Comment: Have you seen this: [Theme customization](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/deep-dive/ui/theme-customization.html)?